# detecting if the current code is running as an app or as web page

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm developing an hybrid application using ionic.

Most of the features would work on mobile web browser. So the final product can be used from an http address as well. But there are certain code segments/features ( such as vibration, background alerts ) which will obviously be for the app version. And those features will only be available on the app version.

What's a good/recommended way to detect the current situation in the code base so that I can do logic such as if (isRunningAsApp) {do this} else {do that}*?

would it be just checking window.location.href and if you get something that starts wiih http:, then it is a mobile app, otherwise it is an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from Ionic's [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/)

```
angular.module('PlatformApp', ['ionic']).controller('PlatformCtrl', function($scope) {

  ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
    // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
  });

  var deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();

  var isWebView = ionic.Platform.isWebView();
  var isIPad = ionic.Platform.isIPad();
  var isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
  var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();
  var isWindowsPhone = ionic.Platform.isWindowsPhone();

  var currentPlatform = ionic.Platform.platform();
  var currentPlatformVersion = ionic.Platform.version();

  ionic.Platform.exitApp(); // stops the app
});
```